# Grep PCRE Regex Non Capturing Groups

Tags: regex, awk, grep

From the following text I wish to extract the following two strings:

`ip-10-x-x-x.eu-west-2.compute.interna`

And

`topology.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a`

Full blob:

```
ip-10-x-x-x.eu-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   18d   v1.20.4-eks-1-20-1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node.app/name=all,topology.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-2,topology.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a
```

Regex with Grep PCRE is being used to extract the strings.

The following regex works on https://regex101.com/

```
(((^ip.*?)(?=(\s)))(?:.*?)((?<=\,)(topology\.kubernetes\.io\/zone.*?)(?=(\s|$))))
```

But when running on on Bash v4.2 with Grep, it pulls back to full blob, rather than the regex groups, as seen here:

```
echo "ip-10-x-x-x.eu-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   18d   v1.20.4-eks-1-20-1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node.app/name=all,topology.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-2,topology.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a" | grep -oP "(((^ip.*?)(?=(\s)))(?:.*?)((?<=\,)(topology\.kubernetes\.io\/zone.*?)(?=(\s|$))))"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `grep` doesn't do anything with capturing groups. It either prints the whole line containing the match, or the entire match if you use `-o`.

Comment: When I clicked on the link labelled "https://regex101.com/" I expected to see your regex and test strings. The link simply took me to the address shown, which is of no value. After testing your regex at regex101 you need to click on "Save Regex" to get a URL that saves your work, to which you can provide a link. Most regex testers provide a way to save your work at a URL.

Answer (score 5):

As Barmer comments, `grep` does not refer capture groups. You need to modify the regex to work with grep:

```
echo "ip-10-x-x-x.eu-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   18d   v1.20.4-eks-1-20-1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node.app/name=all,topology.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-2,topology.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a" | grep -oP "^ip\S+|(?<=\,)topology\.kubernetes\.io\/zone\S*(?=(?:\s|$))"
```

Output:

```
ip-10-x-x-x.eu-west-2.compute.internal
topology.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a
```

If you want to make use of your regex *as is*, try `ripgrep`:

```
echo "ip-10-x-x-x.eu-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   18d   v1.20.4-eks-1-20-1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node.app/name=all,topology.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-2,topology.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a" | rg --pcre2 "(((^ip.*?)(?=(\s)))(?:.*?)((?<=\,)(topology\.kubernetes\.io\/zone.*?)(?=(\s|$))))" -r '$2'$'\n''$5'
```

which will produce the same results.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are ok with `awk`, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk '
match($0,/^ip\S+/){
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  match($0,/,topology\.kubernetes\.io\/zone\S*/)
  print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `match` function of `awk` to match `^ip\S+` then printing its matched value. Then again using 1 more `match` to match regex `,topology\.kubernetes\.io\/zone\S*` to get the 2nd mentioned value by OP then printing only needed output by substr function.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern already captures the parts that you want in groups, but it is not efficient as there are 7 capture groups where you actually only need 2 capture groups.

There are also multiple lookaround assertions that are unnecessary, and can be turned into a match instead or omitted at all.

As already commented and explained, you can not use capture groups with grep, but if you can make use of `gnu awk` you can use match.

```php
awk 'match($0, /^(ip\S+).*,(topology\.kubernetes\.io\/zone\S*)/, a) {
    print a[1]
    print a[2]
}' file
```

Output

```
ip-10-x-x-x.eu-west-2.compute.internal
topology.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a
```

Explanation about the pattern:

```
^(ip\S+).*,(topology\.kubernetes\.io\/zone\S*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(ip\S+)` Capture **group 1**, match `ip` and 1+ non whitespace chars
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `,(topology\.kubernetes\.io\/zone\S*)` Match the `,` and capture the string that you want after it followed by matching optional non whitspace chars using `\S` in **group 2**

---

If you want to output only those 2 matches, another option could be using `sed` and replace the whole line with the 2 capture groups:

```
sed -E 's/^(ip[^[:blank:]]+).*,(topology\.kubernetes\.io\/zone[^[:blank:]]*).*/\1 \2/' file
```

Output

```
ip-10-x-x-x.eu-west-2.compute.internal topology.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a
```